# EF get data by multi condition on each column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to select data from table using the EF and then fill my Dto object.

My Entity (Db) class (source of data) is defined as:

```
[Table(nameof(FulltextDataItem))]
public class FulltextDataItem{
public string? text { get; set; }
public long? Kod { get; set; }
public string? text2 { get; set; }
public long? Kod2 { get; set; }
public string? text3 { get; set; }
public long? Kod3 { get; set; }
public string? text4 { get; set; }
public long? Kod4 { get; set; }
}
```

I need to put condition on each string column, but for example if text2 column doesn't meet condition I still want to check the text, text3, text4 columns, I also need to check long properties to be unique.
Then I need to fill my Dto object with data.

```
    public class LocationsOutputDto
    {
        public long Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public LocationType Type { get; set; }

    }
```

I tried this:

```
            var locSet = ruianDbContext.FulltextDataItems.Where(x => x.Text == input).Select(x => new LocationsOutputDto()
            {
                Code = (long)x.Kod,
                Name = x.text,
                Type = Models.Enums.LocationType.Regions
            });

            var locSet2 = ruianDbContext.FulltextDataItems.Where(x => x.Text2 == input).Select(x => new LocationsOutputDto()
            {
                Code = (long)x.Kod2,
                Name = x.text2,
                Type = Models.Enums.LocationType.District
            });
```

tried to find solution,
help me to code or help me to find solution.

Comment: "check long properties to be unique" Which long properties to be unique? In FulltextDataItem  or LocationsOutputDto ?

Comment: @QingGuo In result there shouldnt be Code with the same value

Comment: Which result? Between  locSet and  locSet2 ? Or DB ?

Comment: result is filled LocationsOutputDto
Code = values from Kod, Kod2, kod3, kod4 properties (duplicity is not allowed)
Name = values from text, text2, text3, text 4 properties(duplicity is not allowed)
Type = is Enum based on that if result is from kod, kod2,kod3 or kod4 property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for example if text2 column doesn't meet condition I still want to
> check the text, text3, text4 columns, I also need to check long
> properties to be unique.

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it,for test I create the data, you can use your data, which  `if (item.text == input)` put first, check it first, then check others.

```
 public IActionResult Privacy(string input)
 {

    var Db= new List<FulltextDataItem>()
    {
        new FulltextDataItem(){Kod=1,text="a",Kod2=2,text2="a",Kod3=3,text3="c",Kod4=4,text4="d"},
        new FulltextDataItem(){Kod=1,text="a",Kod2=2,text2="b",Kod3=3,text3="c",Kod4=14,text4="d"},
        new FulltextDataItem(){Kod=1,text="a",Kod2=2,text2="b",Kod3=3,text3="c",Kod4=24,text4="d"},

    };    


     var locSet = new LocationsOutputDto();

     var list = new  List<LocationsOutputDto>();

     foreach (var item in Db)
     {

         if (item.text == input)
         {
             locSet = new LocationsOutputDto()
             {
                 Code = (long)item.Kod,
                 Name = item.text
                 //Type = Models.Enums.LocationType.Regions
             };
         }
        else if (item.text2 == input)
         {
             locSet = locSet = new LocationsOutputDto()
             {
                 Code = (long)item.Kod2,
                 Name = item.text2
                 //Type = Models.Enums.LocationType.Regions
             };
         }
         else if (item.text3 == input)
         {
             locSet = locSet = new LocationsOutputDto()
             {
                 Code = (long)item.Kod3,
                 Name = item.text3
                 //Type = Models.Enums.LocationType.Regions
             };
         }
         else if (item.text4 == input)
         {
             locSet = locSet = new LocationsOutputDto()
             {
                 Code = (long)item.Kod4,
                 Name = item.text4
                 //Type = Models.Enums.LocationType.Regions
             };
         }

         if (list.Count == 0)
         { list.Add(locSet); }
         if (list.Any(c => c.Code != locSet.Code && c.Name != locSet.Name))
         { list.Add(locSet); }
         
        
     }
     return View();
 }
```

result:

[image]